# beautifulsoup remove all the internal javascript

Tags: javascript, python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

The following is the a simple BeautifulSoup code which has the two internal JavaScript( dont blame about the JavaScript it is just for testing purpose).

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = """
<html><head><title>The Dormouse's story</title>
<script>

var x = 5;
var y = 6;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x + y;
//document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
//document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = y;

</script>
<script>

var x = 5;
var y = 6;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x + y;
//document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
//document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = y;

</script>

</head>
<body>
<p class="title"><b>The Dormouse's story</b></p>

<p class="story">Once upon a time there were three little sisters; and their names were
<a href="http://example.com/elsie" class="sister" id="link1">Elsie</a>,
<a href="http://example.com/lacie" class="sister" id="link2">Lacie</a> and
<a href="http://example.com/tillie" class="sister" id="link3">Tillie</a>;
and they lived at the bottom of a well.</p>

<p class="story">...</p>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
soup.script.decompose()
print soup.prettify()
```

when I ran this code it remove only one `<script>...</script>` from the document(Dom tree) but it don't remove all other script tags. How can we remove all the `<script>, <style>`(internal and inline) tags which are existing in the document

Comment: How do you determine which one to remove? What are the criteria? *Not* having a `src` attribute?

Comment: Actually after posting this soon I got the solution for both of them

    for i in soup.find_all("script"):
     soup.script.decompose()
    for i in soup.find_all("style"):
     soup.style.decompose()

Comment: Note that your version removes **all** `script` tags, not just the ones with inline code. That may be what you wanted, but your question is unclear about that issue.

Answer (score 3):

You need to find all `script` tags that apply; you only looked for the first. Use `soup.find_all()`:

```
for script in soup.find_all('script', src=False):
    script.decompose()
```

This finds all `<script>` tags that do *not* have a `src` attribute.

Comment: Thanks @Martijn Pieters but as soon as I posted that qoestion I got the solution

Comment: @user3611921: so? Now we both found the solution! Others may find it helpful too.

Answer (score 1):

```
for element in soup.findAll('script'):
            element.extract()
```

another alternative, you can replace `'script'` with `['script', 'style']` to get rid of styles as well.

Answer (score 0):

Removing all `<script>` and `<style>` tags in `soup`:

```
 for tag in soup.find_all("script"): soup.script.decompose()
 for tag in soup.find_all("style"): soup.style.decompose()
```